# Jquery Infinite-Scroll not infinite past page 2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite scroll with dynamic data but can't seem to get past page 2...

When the page initially loads I have an offset in the URL so we start at 0, so,

```
test2.html?offset=0
```

this is the code to load the date

```
$offset = $_GET['offset'];

$data = mysql_query("select * from list limit 30 offset $offset;",$db);         

echo '<div id="wall" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">';

while ($databack33 = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

echo '<div class="block">';

echo '<a href=#><img src="'.$databack33[item_pic_url].'"></a>';

echo '</div>';

}
```

Then to load the next page i use:

```
<nav id="page-nav">

<? $offset = $offset+30; ?>

<a href="test2.html?offset=<?=$offset?>"></a>

</nav>
```

This works ok for pages one and two but it then tells me no more pages to load although there is more data.

If I look at the page source it is correct `test2.html?offset=60`

this is the masonry/infinite scroll set up

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var $container = $('#wall');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.block',
    isAnimated: true,
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
      }
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.block',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get infinitescroll working with "offset=" pagination I did the following:

Store the current 'next page' url, and get the offset value.

```
var nextSelector = '#page-nav a';
var origNextUrl = $(nextSelector).attr('href');
var offsetRegex = /(offset=)([0-9]+)/;
var offset = origNextUrl.match(offsetRegex)[2];
```

Then in infinitescroll assign a function to the 'path' option which accepts a page number and returns the url used to load the next page.

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    // other options
    path: function(pageNum) {
        return origNextUrl.replace( offsetRegex, ("$1" + (offset * pageNum)) );
    },
    //callback
 });
```